# Testing for App Engine+Angularjs client - each running on a different port

Tags: angularjs, google-app-engine, gruntjs

*I'm sure my title needs some tweaking, but here's the question:*

Is there a way for me to serve up my AppEngine/Google Endpoint (Python) project using dev_appserver running on a given port (web on 8080, API on 54381), while serving my AngularJS client using a different server (and by necessity a different port, maybe 5000)?

Background:

- The problem I'm encountering is around the structure of my app and
  the tools/processes I can use for dev/testing.
- To leverage existing GruntJS goodness out there I decided to layer my project's App Engine
  server code and AngularJS client code into the directory structure
  created by the [Yeoman Generator](https://github.com/yeoman/generator-angular) for Angular.
- I thought by bringing in this Grunt-like environment I could easily pull in
  [mobile-angular-ui](http://mobileangularui.com/) code as a bower_component and easily link it
  into my main index html page.  This seemed to be the case.
- The issue:  App Engine ended up monitoring the folders/hierarchy under bower_components, which exceeded the file count limit for the app server to monitor (dev_appserver.py said 'There are too many files in your application for '). This generally made me think "there has to be a smarter way".

Options I see:

- Serve the client code from the Grunt-serve server, and the Google Endpoint server using the normal dev_appserver.py.  I believe these need to run on different ports if on the same host.  So I don't know how I can tie the Google Endpoint client loading javascript against the server.
- Google adds a patch to dev_appserver to allow the file-change monitoring code to adhere to exclusions (something discussed in [this Google App Engine Issue](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=11345))
- Find a way to move the files around using grunt plugins so that I effectively re-build a "dist" folder for any external components I use that I point my served client code against.  Avoiding the need to have my App Engine app.yaml expose the entire bower_components folder to make my script includes work.

Answer (score 0):

If you use `grunt-connect-proxy` your Grunt server running on port 5000 will be able to forward requests to the App Engine server on port 8080.

That way you keep Grunt's nice live-reload features.

[This article](http://david-codes.blogspot.com/2014/05/maven-app-engine-and-angularjs.html) explains how to do it on for Java/Maven but the Grunt part is exactly the same.

Here are extracts of my `Gruntfile.js` modified to use the proxy :

```
connect: {
            options: {
                port: 9000,
                // Change this to '0.0.0.0' to access the server from outside.
                hostname: 'localhost',
                livereload: 35729
            }, proxies: [
                {
                    context: [
                        '/_ah',
                        '/admin'
                    ],
                    host: 'localhost',
                    port: 8080,
                    https: false,
                    changeOrigin: false,
                    xforward: false
                }
            ], livereload: {
                options: {
                    open: true,
                    base: [
                        '.tmp',
                        '<%= yeoman.app %>'
                    ],
                    middleware: function (connect, options) {
                        if (!Array.isArray(options.base)) {
                            options.base = [options.base];
                        }

                        // Setup the proxy
                        var middlewares = [require('grunt-connect-proxy/lib/utils').proxyRequest];

                        // Serve static files.
                        options.base.forEach(function (base) {
                            middlewares.push(connect.static(base));
                        });

                        // Make directory browse-able.
                        var directory = options.directory || options.base[options.base.length - 1];
                        middlewares.push(connect.directory(directory));

                        return middlewares;
                    }
                }
            },
...
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-connect-proxy');
...
grunt.registerTask('server', function (target) {
        if (target === 'dist') {
            return grunt.task.run(['build', 'connect:dist:keepalive']);
        }

        grunt.task.run([
            'clean:server',
            'concurrent:server',
            'autoprefixer',
            'configureProxies:server',
            'connect:livereload',
            'watch'
        ]);
    });
```